# How to get this bevel effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, effects

[image: Tell me how?]

I want to create a fire icon in Illustrator. I don't want it to look flat. So, I tried to find design inspiration on google. Then, this image came up. I'm looking for a tutorial to get the same effect, but I don't know what is this effect called. So I came to GD.SE to ask.
*Sorry for the image quality.

Comment: What effect exactly?

Comment: The "bevel" in the end of the fire.... (I don't really know the name)

Comment: That might be considered cell shading but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape is cut into 2 and the lower part is given a gradient to darker color. Here is a example showing the final result and then the shape outlines:

[image]

One can further subside to pieces to get more control over the effect. Also you can use lighter parts in the gradient to make it more visible.

Bevel is a good name for this.